# Why python does not update an external parameter with assignment?

Tags: python, parameter-passing, nonetype

Can anyone explain the reason why python behaves differently in the following two cases please? Much appreciation.

```
def modifyNone(x):
    print("B4:"+str(x))
    # x.append(5)
    x=[5]
    print("In:"+str(x))

a = []
modifyNone(a)
print("After:"+str(a))
```

Output:

```
B4:[]
In:[5]
After:[]
```

Method:

```
def modifyNone(x):
    print("B4:"+str(x))
    x.append(5)
    # x=[5]
    print("In:"+str(x))

a = []
modifyNone(a)
print("After:"+str(a))
```

Output:

```
B4:[]
In:[5]
After:[5]
```

Comment: What about this seems inconsistent to you?

Comment: There is nothing inconsistent going on here. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: @JeffMercado: They are not suggesting anything. We can *guess* at this, but even their first example still shows `After:5` and not `After:1`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Oh oops, I had the feeling he was expecting the value to have changed.

Comment: Your edit didn't make any more sense, but I suspect you just need to read [How do I pass a variable by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/986006)

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry for the unclear post. I messed up my work space and was misled to wrong conclusion. The post has been updated.

Comment: @JeffMercado Sorry for  the unclear post.

Comment: @user1858489: your question is now a duplicate of the post I mentioned.

Comment: @user1858489: they are references to the same object. All python names are just references. You could see this as `x = a`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think I got it. My thought began with a totally wrong observation and turned out to be a ridiculous conclusion. Sorry for the unclear post and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Python is pass by value, so you'll have to reassign a returned value like so:

```
a = modifyNone(a) # where the function returns a value
```

You don't seem to understand variable scope as well, try the documentation.